# AMPScript error for IF statement

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

I'm trying to show a sentence which is saying for example After $20 Cashback for $250.

This is my code:

```
 %%[
var @DisplayCashBack
if empty(@CashBack) then
  set @DisplayCashBack = <br />
else
  set @DisplayCashBack = Concat("After $"@CashBack "Cashback <br /> for $"@CashBackPrice)
endif
]%%
```

I only want to show the value when the field for CashBack is filled in the data extension. When it's empty it shouldn't be shown. I'm receiving a lot of errors and I'm not sure on how to fix it:

```
There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative.
 Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid<br>An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail.
 Script Expression: <
 MemberID: ########
 JobID: 0

 An unrecognized expression appears in a script block.
 Script Expression: <
 MemberID: ########
 JobID: 0
 <br>Invalid Content: <br>set @DisplayCashBack =
There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative.
 Error 2: Script SET Statement Invalid<br>An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail.
 Script Expression: Concat("After $"@CashBack "Cashback <br /> for $"@CashBackPrice)
 MemberID: ########
 JobID: 0

 Invalid characters appear at the end of the parameter value
 Function Call: Concat("After $"@CashBack "Cashback <br /> for $"@CashBackPrice)
 Parameter Value: Na €
 Invalid Character: @
 <br>Invalid Content: <br>set @DisplayCashBack = Concat("Na &#$;"@CashBack "Cashback 
 for &#$;"@CashBackPrice)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you have problems read some of the following pages: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/functions.htm,  https://ampscript.guide/ or just search after the function you are using on SFSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple syntax errors in your code. Please see reviewed code below:

```
%%[
VAR @DisplayCashBack
IF EMPTY(@CashBack) THEN
  SET @DisplayCashBack = "<br />"
ELSE
  SET @DisplayCashBack = CONCAT("After $",@CashBack," Cashback <br /> for $",@CashBackPrice)
ENDIF
]%%
```